# What is $\hat\beta^{Lasso}$ in matrix form

Tags: mathematical-statistics, lasso, ridge-regression

We know that $\hat\beta^{ridge}= (X^TX+\lambda.I)^{-1}X^TY$ but I was wondering if there was a similar equation for $\hat\beta^{Lasso}$.